# Multiple areachart overlaps each other so unable to hover over it

Tags: javafx, layer, overlapping, area-chart

When I want to for example hover over my area chart dot symbols I could not do it because they could overlap each other.

See images:
[Hover over event not triggered - No tooltip shows up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AU0cL.png)

[Hover over event triggered - Tooltip shows up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CCMQs.png)

Maybe I can place the charts in the same layer or something like that to make it work properly?

What I noticed: As the charts loads in, the newer one covers the older one.
I could load the chart which has higher Y axis values first and than the charts with smaller Y axis values.
But that solution would only work in those cases where every single chart points are clearly bigger/smaller than the other chart's points.

Comment: Make the [node](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/12/javafx.controls/javafx/scene/chart/XYChart.Series.html#nodeProperty) of the series [mouse transparent](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/12/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/Node.html#mouseTransparentProperty).

Comment: Thank you! It solved the problem.